# 'Helping' as a noun/gerund/ present participle?

Tags: word-usage

“Thanks for your advice - I found it very helping.” 
Is this use of 'helping' correct in the above sentence? Thanks a lot.

Comment: It should be an adjective because it's modified by 'very', which does not verbs (cf. the unacceptable *she is very walking). But your sentence doesn't sound idiomatic (and is potentially ungrammatical) to me; 'helpful' is a more common adjective.

Answer (score 1):

While technically this is possible- the gerund form does exist, I believe it would be better expressed with helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There is a fixed phrase:

> She lent him a helping hand.

That is, she helped him.

And the -ing form often appears to be adjectival, expressing the kind of something:

> He bought a new pair of running shoes.
>
> Gutenberg is credited with the invention of the printing press.

But we don't normally use **helping** as a predicate adjective / subject complement:

> Your advice was very helping <sup>ungrammatical</sup>.

Yet with some other -ing forms we would have no problem using them in that manner:

> Most men found Morgan beguiling.
>
> The question is intriguing.
>
> The experience was enriching.
>
> A mother's voice is often soothing.
>
> The algorithm was self-adjusting.
>
> She's too judging, always finding fault.
>
> The story was very amusing.
>
> Why are you always so accusing?
>
> The thought of sailing to Tahiti was most alluring.
>
> The amount of lead in the drinking water was quite appalling.
>
> The chocolate cake looked very appealing.
>
> The nod was approving.
>
> The jacket felt too constraining.